# Use _inputElement in child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a parent component with a method that selects a radio box button. Then I want to call this method in the child. How to use the '_inputElement' from the radio button?

```
<app-parent>
   <app-child [radioChange]="callRadio"></app-child>
</app-parent>

  <app-child (click)="radioChange()"></app-child>

ParentComponent(){
  @ViewChild('radioButton', {static: false}) matRadioButton : MatRadioButton;

 callRadio(){
   this.service.onRadioChange();
   const event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
   this.matRadioButton._inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event); 
  }
}

ChildComponent(){
    @Input() radioChange;
}
```

It gives the error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_inputElement')'